# using custom font in css using zip file in react application

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, fonts

I have to use `custom font` in my website.

I am using
`font-family: 'barclays-regular'` but it is not reflecting. so now they have provided `barclays-font.zip` for font and said use `.woff` format. I dont know how to use `.zip` file and `.woff` in our `css`. how to do it? any suggestions or link would be helpful.

I am using these font in our `react app`.

Comment: You have to unpack the zip file and put in the actual fonts.

Comment: thank you @NicolaiChristensen I unzipped it and found .woff file but how to make it as import in css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load custom fonts using `@font-face`.

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-load-and-use-custom-fonts-with-css#loading-a-self-hosted-font-with-font-face) article shows really well how to do this.

Add the font to your project and reference it inside your .css file to be able to use it.